# Azure Website Deploys but displays 500 error

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-core, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

I've published an app to Azure for the first time. When I go to the site I get an HTTP 500 error saying

The page isn't working. *****.azurewebsites.net is currently unable to handle this request.

Looking at the Live Metrics Stream on the Azure Portal it says

Not available: your app is offline or using an older SDK

This is a .Net Core app.

When I published it there were no errors. It said the build and publishing were successful. I'm not sure what other information I can give to help someone help me resolve this.  I'm including some screenshots that may have some helpful information.  I've been stuck for a whole day now.

Below is an error from the Azure Portal:
[image]

Here is my web.config file:
[image]

Here are the general settings from Azure:
[image]

Here are some errors from Azure:
[image]

Here is the Publish page from Visual Studio (disregard the arrow):
[image]

Comment: Hi, It is important to use text instead of use image when asking question on stackoverlflow.(especially the code or the error part) And notice don't upload personal message.

Comment: Make sure the application can be published successfully locally. And follow this document(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-azure-webapp-using-vs?view=aspnetcore-3.0) to publish it to azure.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out.

Earlier I had briefly experimented with using the .net Google Oauth library in my project.  I eventually incorporated Oauth by hand and never removed the code for Google Oauth in Startup.cs.  This didn't cause a problem locally but, the  streaming logs showed an error saying the "ClientID option must be provided".  ClientID is related to the Oauth library.

Viewing the Streaming Logs in Visual Studio is what helped me solve this.  Maybe this will help someone in the future.